# Allow only specific number of quantity products per cart

Tags: shopping-cart, quantity, magento2.2.4

I have to allow only specific numbers of total quantity products in cart. For example i have to allow total 10 products per cart. it's doesn't matter to specific product, products from specific category. Whatever only 1o product per cart allowed. If more than 10 then redirect user to cart page and display message.

Please give me some hints or suggestion. I don't have to use any third party extension.

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if any query generate.

Answer (score 0):

Logged in admin
Tap on left sidebar
`Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Product Stock Options->Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart->10`

Or You Can Use
https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/limit-cart-quantity-for-magento-2.html

Read this
[Maximum Qty Allowed in Cart for the ENTIRE CART](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134573/maximum-qty-allowed-in-cart-for-the-entire-cart)

Comment: Helpful for you@Magecode ?

Comment: It's not useful it's for particular product. I want for whole cart not for specific product. in short total quantity in cart for all the products.

Comment: Please check bscommerce module

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Goto Admin -> Stores -> Configuration

[image]

2) For individual settings, Go to product details

[image]

3) Click Advanced Inventory

[image]

Comment: It's not useful it's for particular product. I want for whole cart not for specific product. in short total quantity in cart for all the products.